# Using Revmob Ad SDK with Android app on Game Maker

Tags: android, ads, revmob

Are Revmob ads compliant with all Google Policies when used in an Android app made with Game Maker Studio.

If yes do you need to show any message to the end user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RevMob is compliant with all Google Policies.

There's no need to show any message for your end users.

For instructions on integration, check the [documentation](https://revmobmobileadnetwork.com/sdk)

Comment: can i use the same media ID (ad unit) across all platforms  I.e same app on Play and Amazon?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't.

A different media Id must be used for each store.